# How to make a function work with optimize in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a problem with a function that's telling me it can't convert to `float`.

I took this function from an operation above and I called it `func0`:

```
func0 = -2.59132902231451 * j ** 1.0
       - 2.36920574650032 * j ** 2.0
       + 0.809974823421635 * j ** 3.0
       + 4.22334771487835
```

I want to solve a non-linear system using `optimize`:

```
def sol(g):
    kt1, j = g
    return (kt1 - func0, kt1 - T * j ** 2 / (1.025 * D ** 2 * VA ** 2))
kt1, j = optimize.fsolve(equations, (0.01, 0.9))
```

The error:

> Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.

The weird thing is, if I take the whole formula, it works. But with `func0` it's not working.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You're returning a tuple, not an array. Does wrapping the tuple in `numpy.array` help?

Comment: Can you tell me where i have to put the numpy.array?, because I didn´t get you.

Answer (score 0):

```
from numpy import array
j = 1
func0 = -2.59132902231451 * j ** 1.0 - 2.36920574650032 * j ** 2.0 + 0.809974823421635 * j ** 3.0 + 4.22334771487835
D=1
VA = 1
T=1
def sol(g):
    kt1, j = g
    return (kt1 - func0, kt1 - T * j ** 2 / (1.025 * D ** 2 * VA ** 2))

print(array(sol((1,1))))
```

Comment: you have D, VA and T ok you could put 1, but j and kt are you independient variable, and you didn´t use the optimize function.

Comment: thats because I don't what's module has optimize function. I only showed you how to convert a tuple into a numpy.array, as suggested by Perfi

Comment: Yeah but is not helping, my only problem is why i get a solution when i try with the whole formula, but when i called the whole formula func0, is not working inside the optimize funtion. It´s killing me...